# How can we download mp3 file from res/raw/song.mp3 and store in local Storage not SdCard

Tags: android

How can we download a mp3 file from res/raw/song.mp3 and save in local storage not in SdCard i search a lot but not find any solution regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download is not required for this work ! , to do this , we use copy method ! [ copy file from raw folder to local storage ] :

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Your song or file [in raw folder]
        YourFile(R.raw.song);
        }

    // Start saving the file in external storage ...
    private void YourFile(int Resource){
        String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
            "/song.mp3"; // File path
        try{
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(Resource);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                end();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void end () {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File saved in /storage/emulated/0/song.mp3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

And **permissions** :

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: this doesn't save any file in my external storage, where do you create the new file ?  myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename); ???

Comment: it saved but can't be play. why?